# How to put a div inside a table

Tags: html, html-table

I would like to put a `<div>` inside a table but the `<div>` has to cover 2 cells and 2 rows:

[image]

For example I would like to put  :

```
(WonderWidget ,2ND Quarter)
(WonderWidget ,3ND Quarter)
(MegaWidget ,2ND Quarter)
(MegaWidget ,3ND Quarter)
```

into a `<div>` is that possible?

Comment: No, because HTML elements have to be properly nested. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to modify the div so the middle one will have a different formating and have a different content (shadows, words ect) but i need them to be like a single unit

Comment: If you're just looking to change the styling of some of the content, consider using a span tag instead of a div. From a semantic standpoint, span is meant to provide inline styling overrides. Divs are meaningless containers.

Comment: "i need them to be like a single unit". Why, and in which way "like"? Different content has nothing to do with div or no div, for formatting purposes, use Brandons approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember! A div can stay in a table only in td. Therefore you need to make a td as "big" as two rows and two columns.

Here I made an explicit example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLpay/  and is something like that :

```
 <tr>
    <td>WonderWidget</td>
    <td>$x</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">$x</td>
    <td>$x</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Welcome! I' m glad I could be helpful to you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi it's very easy and it's possible. Just use [colspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) and [rowspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp)

**Code:**

```
<style>
table, table * {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>PRODUCT</th>
            <th>1ST QUARTER</th>
            <th>2ND QUARTER</th>
            <th>3RD QUARTER</th>
            <th>4TH QUARTER</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>SupaWidget</td>
            <td>$x</td>
            <td>$x</td>
            <td>$x</td>
            <td>$x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>WonderWidget</td>
            <td>$x</td>
            <td colspan="2">$x</td>
            <td>$x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MegaWidget</td>
            <td>$x</td>
            <td colspan="2">$x</td>
            <td>$x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HyperWidget</td>
            <td>$x</td>
            <td>$x</td>
            <td>$x</td>
            <td>$x</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Visit this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B7spU/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
    <div>WonderWidget </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>header1</th><th>header2</th><th>header3</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td colspan = "2">
     <div class="myStyle">
      Entry for headers 1 and 2
     </div>
   </td>
   <td>
     Entry for header 3
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

the same principal can be followed for added rowspans

Additionally check http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp